# make_table() does not work inside if else statement in iPython(Jupyter)

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am checking if file exists or not using os.path.exists(), and if it exists I want to display the table, table contains the information collected from the csv files using dataframes, however when I write make_table() inside if else statement it does not show its content but whenever I write it outside it shows me the data. This should not be the case since I want to display the data if file exists. Please look at my code below

```
import pandas
from ipy_table import *
...

save_path = select_season(season)
name_of_file =select_league(league)

filename = save_path + name_of_file +".csv"

new_df_home = df[df.FTR == 'H']
new_df_away = df[df.FTR == 'A']
new_df_draw = df[df.FTR == 'D']

if os.path.exists(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".csv"))

    Matches = [
        ['Matches Played', 'Home Wins', 'Draws', 'Away Wins','Full time Home     goals', 'Full time Away goals', 
         'Half time Home goals', 'Half time Away goals'],
          [df['Div'].count(), new_df_home['Div'].count(),     new_df_draw['Div'].count(), new_df_away['Div'].count(),df['FTHG'].sum(),
           df['FTAG'].sum(),df['HTHG'].sum(),df['HTAG'].sum()]];

    make_table(Matches)

else:
    print("This record is not present")
```

Comment: Have you checked that that if-branch executes? E.g. with a print statement after you create the data frame?

Comment: Yes, I wrote print(1) inside if branch and execute the code, it prints 1. So, it is going inside if branch but not executing make_table(Matches)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to store the result of the make_table(Matches):

```
table = make_table(Matches)
```

And end your code with:

```
...
else:
   print("This record is not present")
table
```

so that table is print at the end...